# Concluding that a finitely generated module is free?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a local Noetherian domain, and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Furthermore, let's suppose there exists $k>0$ such that
$$
\dim_{R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}}M_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}M_\mathfrak{p}=k
$$ 
for any prime $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{spec}(R)$.

I've been curious though, how does this imply that $M$ is in fact a free module? I figure you want to extract some basis for $M$ from a generating set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, and this is where the dimension condition comes in. However, after localizing at $\mathfrak p$ and taking quotients, I'm losing sight of how to connect to the two ideas.

Can someone explain why $M$ is free here? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know [Nakayama's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma)? It doesn't immediately solve your problem, but it seems related.

Comment: @DylanMoreland: You were indeed correct, if my proof is correct.

Comment: @Rankeya Ah, my eyes skipped over the domain condition, so I didn't get anywhere. I'll take a look at your proof!

Comment: This is given as an exercise in Lang's Algebra, page 444, with a hint. Apparently, it is enough for the ring to have no nilpotent elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m \subset R$ be the unique maximal ideal of the Noetherian ring. By hypothesis, $M/mM$ has dimension $k$ as an $R/m$ vector space. So, let $x_1 + mM, ..., x_k +mM$ be a basis for $M/m$. Then one can show using Nakayama's lemma (see proposition 2.8 in Atiyah-Macdonald) that $M = <x_1,...,x_k>$.

Let $p \in Spec(R)$. Then $M_p/pM_p$ is generated by $\{\frac{x_1}{1} + pM_p, ..., \frac{x_k}{1} + pM_p\}$ as a $R_p/pR_p$ module, hence is a basis for $M/pM_p$.

Let $r_1x_1 + ... + r_kx_k = 0$ in $M$ $(r_i \in R)$. Then, for all $i$, $\frac{r_i}{1} + pR_p = 0$ in $R_p/pR_p$. Thus, $\frac{r_i}{1} \in pR_p$. Hence, $r_i \in p$. But, $p$ was an arbitrary prime ideal, and since $R$ is a domain $(0)$ is prime. So, $r_i \in (0)$, and we are done.

Comment: If this proof is correct note that this method of proof will work if $R$ is a Noetherian reduced ring.

Comment: Also, I do not think one needs to assume that $R$ is Noetherian. I have a feeling I did not use Noetherianity anywhere in this proof. Proposition 2.8 from Atiyah-Macdonald works for local rings in general. So, your statement is true for any finitely generated module over a local reduced ring.

Comment: Thanks Rankeya. By the way, in the second paragraph, did you mean to say $R_p/pR_p$ module, not $R_p/pM_p$ module?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for pointing it out.